# Gwt requestFactory validator not found

Tags: gwt, validation, bean-validation, requestfactory

in my referenced library of my project i have: hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar

but when i run my project, i get

```
[WARN] Server class 'org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
 [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Users/bob/Downloads/spring-framework-3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-3.1.2.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/C:/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201208080121-rel-r42/gwt-2.4.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
[WARN] Server class 'org.springframework.expression.PropertyAccessor' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Users/bob/Downloads/spring-framework-3.1.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-3.1.2.RELEASE/dist/org.springframework.expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/C:/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201208080121-rel-r42/gwt-2.4.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
[WARN] Server class 'net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Users/bob/Downloads/lib/cglib-2.2.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/C:/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201208080121-rel-r42/gwt-2.4.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
[WARN] Server class 'javax.validation.ValidationException' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
   [WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201208080121-rel-r42/gwt-2.4.0/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
   For additional info see: file:/C:/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201208080121-rel-r42/gwt-2.4.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
14 sept. 2012 13:48:10 com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.ReflectiveServiceLayer <clinit>
INFO: Unable to initialize a JSR 303 Bean Validator
javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:264)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
```

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [file:/C:/Applications/eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201208080121-rel-r42/gwt-2.4.0/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.4.0/distro-source/core/src/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html)?

The answer is just there: server-side JARs should be in *WEB-INF/lib*.